# Manual price range for Woocommerce with min-max, only min, and only max price user input

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price

I have come up with price range filter mith min. and max. price. Nothing fancy.

```
<div class="price-filter-container">
  <form method="get" action="/sklep">
    <div class="price-filter">
      <label for="min-price"></label>
      <input type="number" name="min_price" id="min-price" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['min_price']) ? esc_attr($_GET['min_price']) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('od:', 'text-domain'); ?>">
      <label for="max-price"></label>
      <input type="number" name="max_price" id="max-price" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['max_price']) ? esc_attr($_GET['max_price']) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('do:', 'text-domain'); ?>">
      <button type="submit" class="button"><?php esc_html_e('Zastosuj', 'pvg'); ?></button>
      <button type="button" class="button button-clear"><?php esc_html_e('Wyczyść', 'pvg'); ?></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var clearButton = document.querySelector('.price-filter .button-clear');
      if (clearButton) {
        clearButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var form = this.closest('form');
          var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
          for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].value = '';
          }
        });
      }

      var form = document.querySelector('.price-filter form');
      if (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          var minPrice = document.querySelector('#min-price');
          var maxPrice = document.querySelector('#max-price');
          var minPriceValue = minPrice.value.trim();
          var maxPriceValue = maxPrice.value.trim();
          
          if (minPriceValue !== '' && maxPriceValue === '') {
            maxPrice.disabled = true;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</div>
```

Now I cannot figure out, how to make it return any results if only min. or max. price is added. It returns "no products found" and works fine with both inputs.